# Sorting large, binary, fixed length records with QSORT

Tags: c++, sorting, record, binary-data, qsort

I would like to sort a big file which contains 20-byte (it's not a structure) binary records with a help of `qsort`. There are 800 000 000 records in the file.

I have 2 questions:

- what is the best way to sort 20-byte records in a compare function of `qsort`?

  ```
  int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
  ```
- and simply how to do the sort with 800 000 000 records? I cannot put it all in a memory..

Comment: 800000000 records 20 bytes each ?

Comment: Why quicksort? Use external sort (which is based on merge sort), or some Terra-sort existing implementation that uses muti-processing to sort.

Comment: > Why quicksort? Simply I don't know other solution..

Comment: "can not put it all in memory" is perhaps true if you have a 32-bit process, but in a 64-bit system with large memory, it should fit quite nicely. If you don't want to load into memory, then using some sorting method for "files" is probably the best method.

Comment: As mentioned, external sorts are usually some type of merge sort. If you read / write data in large amounts, like 10MB to 100MB at a time, then random access overhead is reduced and you can use a larger k-way merge sort, with k equal to 8 or 16, depending on how much memory you have available.

Comment: Aside: if you're using C++, then I know of no reason why you should ever use `std::qsort`, because you can use `std::sort` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As many of the commenters mentioned, this looks like a great job for an [external sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting), a sorting algorithm that's designed for the case where you can't fit all of the objects to sort into memory at one time. Many sorting algorithms can be adapted for this setting, such as quicksort, bucket sort, and mergesort. If you want a relatively simple option, consider using a k-way external mergesort: split the data apart into a number of ranges such that each range fits into memory, sort each range in memory, and write the results back to disk. Then, do a k-way merge on those ranges: open each file for reading, read one large block of each file at a time, and use a normal k-way merge operation on those blocks. Any time you exhaust all the elements in a block, just read another block out of the file.